# Why is my delegation between two vc's not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, delegates

I have two view controllers. My first is my menu which contains my highscore and a button which performs a modal segue to my second view controller which is my game. Whenever my player loses the game if he beat his highscore I want it to update on the menu.

Right now, when my player loses the game, I create a UIAlertView with 2 buttons, the first is main menu and the second is restart. Here is my simplified code with my attempting to update my high score via delegation.

```
        @protocol highScoreProtocol <NSObject>

        -(void)updateHighScore:(int) score;


        @end

        @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> //i have this delegate implemented because i have a uiialertview
        @property (nonatomic) int score;
        @property (nonatomic, weak) id <highScoreProtocol> delegateHighScore;



        @implementation ViewController
        @synthesize score=_score;
        @synthesize delegateHighScore=_delegateHighScore;

            -(void)lostGame{
            [self.delegateHighScore updateHighScore:self.score]; //this is where i try to call the method that should update my high score if necessary but this doesn't actually work
        UIAlertView *losingScreen=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Over" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Score Is %d", self.score] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Main Menu" otherButtonTitles:@"Restart", nil]; //once the user loses the game i have an alert view show giving the option to either restart the game or go to the main menu where the high score is
            }

        -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
              if (buttonIndex==0) {
                 //here i'm segueing back to my main menu because he would have pressed the 'main menu' button  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MainMenu" sender:self];

            } else if (buttonIndex==1){
                //here i just reset my attributes and reset my level because he would have pressed the 'restart button'
            }
        }

    @end

            @interface MenuVC : UIViewController <highScoreProtocol>
            @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelHighScore; //the labelhighscore is the highscore number

            @end


@implementation MenuVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    vc.delegateHighScore=self;//here is set the delegate as myself which i think i'm supposed to do for some reason

}

-(void)updateHighScore:(int)score{
    if (score>[self.labelHighScore.text integerValue]) { 
        self.labelHighScore.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
    }
    NSLog(@"does this method even run");

// this is the method that updates the highscore which I want to run
// but it doesn't, notice I even made an 'nslog' to see if the method
// even runs but I never ever even got a log out in the debugger,
// so this method never runs.
}
```

If I just need a little help, or if I'm doing everything completely wrong and going about this task the wrong way, please say.

Comment: Is vc nil? I don't know if that init method correctly creates your view controller.

Comment: How are you presenting ViewController from MenuVC, can you show that code?

Comment: i just have a button that modally segues to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because this:

```
ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
vc.delegateHighScore=self;
```

Instantiates a NEW viewcontroller, that has completely nothing to do with the one you are interacting with.

I assume you are using storyboards so, create an identifier for your viewcontroller (on the interface builder -> select your viewcontroller -> identity inspector tab -> write a name where it says Storyboard ID)

And then add this instead of the previous code:

```
ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];
vc.delegateHighScore = self;
```

**Edit:**

Add this to your button action (but **delete the segue from the interface builder AND delete this code from the viewDidLoad**)

```
ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];
vc.delegateHighScore = self;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: oh no, i just tried it and i got a crash saying, 2012-11-07 20:24:35.530 Rockets[11378:c07] -[MenuVC setDelegateHighScore:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756e240

Comment: you are using the interface builder right? add NSLog(@"%@",vc); between those to lines of code to make sure its not nil.

Comment: this means that you are assigning the wrong delegate. your interface builder identifier must be set on the ViewController window, not on the MenuVC window

Comment: I just fixed it but when my app started running it crashed code and i saw that there was like 40 threads all saying setHighScoreDelegate

Comment: you have to be more specific. Its not running at all anymore? You also must be miss interpreting the error. It is probably the call order what you are seeing.

Comment: oh never mind that was because of something stupid i did but yeah i fixed it and it just does nothing, it runs and everything but the problem doesn't get fixed

Comment: I just noticed, your delegate is probably being instantiated then deallocated because you are not keeping it around. Delete the modal transition from the button (in the interface builder) and add an actino for this button. The button action should be as in the modified answer I provide.

Comment: present modal view controller is deprecated in ios 6 /:

Comment: [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil]; When a method is deprecated just click on it so that you can see on the right panel what it should be replaced for. Btw even if it is deprecated most methods will still work.

Comment: oh cool i did it and when i lose the game i got my nslog so i know the method atleast ran, but when i segue back to my menu screen the highscore number is still zero, my guess is that when my update highscore method gets called in my game, the highscore actually changes correctly, but then when i segue back to the menu screen, it defaults back to zero

Comment: when you "segue back" are you using a button or a segue in the interface builder? if you are then you are not segueing back, you are creating a new instance of your menu and showing it. you should "dismiss" the viewcontroller to go back. (again in the interface builder delete the segue for the go back button and add [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; as the button action)

Comment: PD: please mark the answer as correct (checkbox mark) if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you create a local variable, vc, in your viewDidLoad method, this is not the same one that you create in the button method where you create your modal segue. That's not the right place to set the delegate. Set yourself to the delegate in that button method using whatever reference you create (or have) to the instance of ViewController that you're segueing to. If you need more information or a code sample, post that button method, so I can see how you are segueing.

After Edit: Then you should implement prepareForSegue:sender: and do this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [(ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: my menu vc is the first vc that gets loaded, and on it all i have is a start button which i created on the storyboard and i control dragged the button to my game vc modally